# Amazon DynamoDB table takes too long to delete

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Every once in a while, the Amazon DynamoDB tables takes too long to delete (~20 mins). I have faced this issue while deleting table from console or boto3 API. Has anyone faced this issue. How did they deal with it?

I don't have any snippets or screenshots to attach.

Comment: Dynamo tables tend to be slow on deletes - around 5 minutes is quite normal. 

The problem is often people want to delete the table and re-create it as cleanup, but this will inject a downtime. Renaming also isn't fast - so deleting the items (and pay for that) is an option or to use TTLs.

Comment: The downtime of few mins is acceptable in our scenario. Just that we want to know the max possible duration and we will adjust the batch processes accordingly. But the variation (from few seconds to 20-25 max) is what is causing the issue. Is there a maximum time limit for the operation that aws has specified?

Comment: There is no documentation I am aware of. But you an open a case on AWS and ask the support if there are any guarantees. 

I personally switched to another store a while ago, also nosql and even there times are not really predictable as they depend on the load of the database cluster.

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB tables generally take a while to delete (longer than most other resources in AWS).

There's no inherent explicit reason stated for this which you can point to and I haven't been able to find a max duration from any part of the docs, whether user guide or SDKs.

Tables for me typically take around 5 minutes so 20 minutes may or may not be an outlier depending on, for example, if you have multi-region replication enabled by using global tables etc.

It's not an issue per se and there's no way to deal with it other than waiting for the job to finish - DynamoDB's architecture is distributed by nature and I assume they wouldn't be able to give you an SLA estimate even if they wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using boto3 to delete the table you can use a waiter (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#waiters) to wait until the table no longer exists.